# Average of list of floating point numbers Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the average of a bunch of floating point numbers from a file using bc in bash.

right now, when I add I use:

```
let "sum=sum+${NUMBERS[$i]} | bc"
```

`
I get syntax errors when I do this however. Syntactically, what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bc is expecting standard input.  Since the first command has no standard output, bc has no input in this case.  Try this:

```
sum=`echo $sum+${NUMBERS[$i]} | bc -l`
```

Comment: This helped a lot, because I was not clear on why that wasn't working. bc needs output from a standard command, such as echo, correct? Now I'm having another issue. to get the average, I tried doing average=`echo $sum/$NUMLEN | bc` just like you showed me before, but when I echo it ( echo $average | bc ) it strips off the decimals and shows as just an int

Comment: I should have mentioned it earlier, but when invoking bc use the -l flag to enable its math library.  So average=$(echo $sum/$NUMLEN | bc -l) will do what you want.  The "|" operator in bash takes the output from the command on its left and feeds it to the command on its right as input.  So using echo will output the expression onto standard output and then "|" will feed that into bc as input.